# upload multiple documents in sharepoint with content type form

Tags: sharepoint, forms, upload, document

my question is this: how can I upload multiple documents in a sharepoint site and still have that page woth the form saying content type like it does when I upload one document?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you re-phrase the question? Not really sure what is is you are asking...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be a current design decision with SharePoint 2007, wherein they believe that if you are uploading multiple documents there should NOT be one catch all for the content type.  I could be wrong on this, but I think this may be an enhancement in SharePoint 2010